# C# Proxies Return 403, Time out Or 1/100 work

Tags: c#, proxy, timeout, http-status-code-403

Good afternoon,
Today I have the following question:
I have a list of proxies which I am using to send requests out however, only one in 100 good WORKING proxies that I have checked work. Any idea why this could be happening? They either time out or return 403 Forbidden.
This is my code:

```
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.Timeout = 15000;
                //request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36";
                request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-us,en;q=0.5");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Referer = "www.refLink.com";
                //WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy(pro, 80); //proxy
                WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy(ip, port);
                //request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                request.Proxy = myProxy;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Any ideas appreciated. I have tried both with request.Proxy.Credentials, request.Accept = "asterisk/asterisk", even the CookieContainer.
I have it set to time out for 15 seconds, times out close to instantly.

The main problem however, I see that most proxies should work but get the 403 Forbidden..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have even made it access IP websites to check my IP and they work.

Comment: Are you sure the proxies actually work? If you're getting a 403, then that means a connection was made successfully and that's what the server returned.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I believe so, I went to get the response from websites that show your IP and the IP was the one of the proxy. I have another request, request2 which I use to POST to a website and it does just that, works but only 1/40-50ish. However, the 403 appears on the Exception side with the program still running due to catch {} as "+  Caught: " The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." (System.Net.WebException) Exception Message = "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.", Exception Type = "System.Net.WebException" ".

Comment: @GabrielLuci I mean, I would expect more proxies to work. Maybe the website that handles the request denies proxies? But why have one out of so many actually work. I have a proxy thing and those show as not blacklisted or something like that.

Comment: Do the proxies use authentication?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I doubt that so many of them off a public/private website would.